# closing fullscreen video in UIWebView causes strange behavior (?)

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, fullscreen

I've got a local MP4 video running in UIWebView in full screen mode as usual, but recently it causes this absurd behavior: almost all the ViewControllers, TableViewControllers (XIB files) are being added again – doubled. I believe it started happening since iOS6.

ANY clue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know that since iOS6 closing full screen video (embedded in HTML file launched in `UIWebView` in my case) causes execution of `viewWillAppear` in all views – there all my mess happened, so this problem solved.

Meanwhile I've detected another strange behavior: requesting a movie file directly in `UIWebView` (not nested in HTML file like i did before) and closing it from full screen causes `UIWebView` to load previous file (like `goBack` function). Bug?

Comment: so how did you solve the problem exactly? I have the same issue, that viewWillAppear is called again.

Comment: simply by removing any actions from `viewWillAppear`, but if you really need something there, you've got to give some kind of `if (movie is not played) {your actions}'. sorry, didn't notice your question earlier.